# *All* forces in stacked objects on ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

I want to reference the first answer to this previous question:

[How is an object kept on a table is at rest?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205454/how-is-an-object-kept-on-a-table-is-at-rest)

First, the problem I'm actually working on is a mat sitting on the ground and a box sitting on top of the mat, but as far as I can tell, these are identical situations with the table/ball scenario (object on object on ground, at rest, touching.)

Looking at the first answer given (and accepted it seems), there are 4 pairs of forces: 2 from gravity ("field"), 2 from "contact."  Fine so far.  My question is, don't all objects have gravitational forces ("pull") between them, and although extremely small in magnitude, isn't there a fifth pair of forces that would include the gravitational pull between the ball and the table (or in my case, the mat and the box)?

Here is the free body diagram from the other answer for reference (the diagram I think is missing a pair of forces):

[image: Previous Answer Free Body Diagram]

Comment: There are a pair of fifth force which for all practical purposes are so small compared with the other forces they can be neglected.

Comment: yes, way too small